# Group By in HttpGet in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, group-by, http-get

I am working in a web page where there is a list of orders that customers made. I have my backend in ASP NET Core and my front end in Angular. The problem I am facing is that when I make a get request with group by I got the error

"System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (o.ClientId),
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
EntityType: Order
ValueBufferExpression:
(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
IsNullable: False
)
)"

This is how my [web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe7Fe.png) looks. What I don't want is to have repeated records.

This is what I have try:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Order>>> GetOrders()
    {
        return await _database.Orders
                .Include(c => c.Client)
                .GroupBy(c => c.ClientId)
                .Select(c => c.OrderBy(x => x.ClientId).FirstOrDefault())
                .ToListAsync();
    }
```

My class in ASP NET Core is:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I realized I was missing a variable in my class, so this is what it looks like:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but according to the code, each order only have one client, so... what does this for ? `.GroupBy(c => c.ClientId).Select(c => c.OrderBy(x => x.ClientId).FirstOrDefault())`

Comment: It will be better if you can clarify the expected result. 1 customer may make more than 1 order. Hence the result is correct as it queried based on orders. **What I don't want is to have repeated records.**. Are you try to get each customer without duplicate? Maybe [Enumerable.Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) meets your requirement.

Comment: after you GroubBy Client, All client in select is equal. if you need get to client use this. .GroupBy(c => c.Client)
.Select(c => c.Key)

Comment: @YongShun That is right, 1 customer can make more than 1 order. I got an image column in my database so Distinct does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to sort your result based on client Id. In that case you may try:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Order>>> GetOrders()
    {
        return await _database.Orders
                .Include(c => c.Client)
                .GroupBy(c => c.ClientId)
                .OrderBy(c=>c.Key)
                .Select(x=> as your need)
                .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Edited: Added select based on requirement

Comment: I got this error in code: Cannot implicitly convert typ System.Collections.Generic.List>>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'

Comment: Well, you have to select the result based on your need. if you do not wish to sort the result based on the client, you do not need to group the result.

Comment: As per your result image link, a simple _database.Orders.Include(c=>c.Client).ToListAsync() is enough. But this is a list of orders and you may have multiple orders for a customer. Do you wanna discard more than one order for a client? That should not make sense considering the business requirement, right?

Comment: What I am doing is that if the business wants to see the details of the order will click the eye button that I placed and then it will show them all the orders from only that client